# Как аналитические сервиса Яндекса и Гугла реагируют на асинхронную загрузку страниц?

Tags: javascript, seo, google-analytics, html5-history-api, яндекс-метрика

Если контент значительного кол-во страниц сайта грузится аяксом, нужно ли в яндекс-метрике и гугл-аналитике что-то делать для того чтобы преходы на эти страницы были зафиксированы? Либо эти сервисы сами поймут что юзер перешел на такую странцу?

Например, есть страница `site.ru/my-page`, на нее можно перейти по прямой ссылке и она отобразится как обычно, и можно перейти по ссылке внутри сайта (допустим `/my-page` - это пункт меню, на который можно кликнуть находясь на любой странице сайта) - в таком случае контент `/my-page` загрузится асинхронно и отобразится в таком же виде как и если перейти по прямой ссылке. Важно, что при загрузке этого контента аяксом, в строке браузере меняется url на `/my-page` используя history api (не просто молча берем контент и отображаем).

Когда я гуглил инфу по этому поводу, я столкнулся с тем, что на одних ресурсах пишут что обязательно нужно отсылать в аналитику события типа `pageview` - иначе переходы внутри сайта не будут зафиксированы. А на других пишут, что якобы при использовании history api никаких событий дополнительно слать в аналитические сервисы не нужно, они и так все зафиксируют т.к. они реагируют на изменения в адресной строк браузера.

Вопрос в том, где истина? Как правильно поступить в моем случае? Если не слать ничего о переходах - потеряю необходимую статистику или ее часть, а если слать - то статистика может быть неправильна из-за дублирования событий. Если кто-то знает как это на самом деле работает в настоящий момент - объясните пожалуйста. Конкретно интересует поведение яндекс-метрики и гугл-аналитики.